# Introducing new values for a categorical feature

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently evaluating ML on some flight related data.

One of the feature in my dataset is an airport IATA code.

Upon the whole evaluation dataset this feature is what I call finite (all the values are known in advance) which is pretty nice for its encoding and for the training phase.

Example :

```
Currently know values ['JFK', 'ARN', 'CDG', 'ZRH']
Representation of CDG [-1,-1,1,-1]
```

Now once the model is trained and used with production data, some new airport codes might show up which will result in a new category which is unknown to the trained model and will be represented in my feature array as a new column.

What is the usual way to deal with those cases ? Should the whole model be retrained including the new value ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I come across a problem like this, I usually try to re-run my model with the new data because I can't predict my outcome without knowing the effect of a certain value within my variable.

You could also assume what the effect of the value might be if you have some way of finding out.

For example, if you run a logistic model and you have the variable 'City', which has levels:

- London
- Tokyo
- Paris
- LA

And you're trying to predict a certain outcome, you can see the effect of each of these cities individually on your outcome variable. If you then get new data and there is the city 'Manchester' in the new data, you could either re-train your model to include 'Manchester', or you can look at the effect of 'Manchester' individually against your outcome variable and you might find that it has a very similar effect that 'London' has, so then you can assume they have the same effect and carry on with your original model.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was about to re-consider this variable and "cast" it to a country code which has a lower dimension and can be integrated into the starting model.

Comment: Sorry for a very late reply, but yeah that's another option if the effects of individual cities are similar. 

PS If I have answered your question, do you mind ticking the question as solved?